# Conversion of the regular expression of VBA code to C# code

Tags: c#, excel, vba

`sFileText = Replace(sFileText, vbCrLf & " ", "|")`. 
Can anyone tell me how to convert this regular expression of VBA Code to C# code?

Comment: That's not a regex but a plain string replace

Comment: `sFileText = sFileText.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "|").Replace(" ", "|");` No regex here, just using string

Comment: okay!!how do I convert into c#?

Comment: @krishna what I have written is C#...

Answer (score 1):

The VB6 [`Replace`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bt3szac5(v=vs.90).aspx) function is just replacing one string with another. Therefore you can use [`String.Replace`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1(v=vs.110).aspx) in .NET. [`VbCrlf`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.constants.vbcrlf(v=vs.110).aspx) is the same as `Environment.NewLine` *:

```
string result = sFileText.Replace(System.Environment.NewLine + " ", "|");
```

**well, not quite the same. `VbCrlf` is a constant as opposed to  `NewLine` that works also on unix. So `"\r\n"` for non-Unix  and `"\n"` for Unix platforms*

Comment: Check my comment, they also wanted spaces

Comment: @AlfieGoodacre: fixed